# How to start two different Intents in alistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I am new to android and a little bit confused. i have a listView with image and text. Where, if I click on a Image it should start an activity, and if I click on text another activity.

Cod:
in

```
onCrete(){
listView = getListView();}

myBaseAdapterItemActivity = new MyBaseAdapterItemActivity(
                    ItemActivity.this, placeNameList);
            setListAdapter(myBaseAdapterItemActivity);

            myBaseAdapterItemActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();

            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

// One Activity I can start without any problem

// In xml File I set for image clicable to true.

// What I want to do is like this

if(view.getId() == R.id.imageId)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else if(view.getID == R.id.textId)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
}}
```

And whenever I click on Image it does not not either in textView.
Any Idea

Comment: Set onClickListener on each ImageView and TextView you have in MyBaseAdapterItemActivity, you do not have to use setOnItemClickListenr

Comment: Do you have some touchable components in your list? Take a look at the following link: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/ . Your comment 'In xml File I set for image clickable to true' indicates that your image takes focus (for the click event). Could you add android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to your imageview? Also could you check if you get the right ID at view.getID()?

Comment: @Chor WaiChun  Could you please provide some code for MyBaseAdapterItemACtivity and in the main Activity

Comment: I think you can refer to answer by itsrajesh4uguys, just refer to getView method, the other parts will confuse you, and I think you have already done those other parts.

Comment: Did you take a look at the view's focus? (As I suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.
Your adapter should be like below code. then your text and image click will create new activity.

Hi the code should be like below Hope this helps you.

```
package com.example.listwithclick;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ListView listView1;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity=this;

        listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(new MyAddapter(MainActivity.this));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     class MyAddapter extends BaseAdapter {
            Context rContext;
            private LayoutInflater rInflater;

            public MyAddapter(Context c) {

                rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

                rContext = c;

            }      

            public MyAddapter(Activity imagebinding) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                activity = imagebinding;        

                rContext = imagebinding;
                rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(imagebinding);
                rContext = imagebinding;
                rInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  


                return 10;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                convertView = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
                final MyDat mydat = new MyDat();                

                mydat.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                mydat.textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Toast.makeText(rContext, "text", 1000).show();
                        Intent image= new Intent(rContext,TextActivity.class);
                        startActivity(image);
                    }
                });

                mydat.imageView1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                mydat.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(rContext, "image ", 1000).show();

                        Intent image= new Intent(rContext,ImageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(image);
                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }

            class MyDat {


                TextView  textview;
                ImageView imageView1;


            }

        }

}
```

Comment: I want within on Click to start an Intent, which means if i click an image an ImageActivity hast to be stared, if on text on TextActivity. but I can not start activity in onClick()

Comment: I get an Error as follows : java.lang.NullPointerException at com.project.test.Adapters.MyBaseAdapterItemActivity.getView(MyBaseAdapterItemActivity.java:82) at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461) etc, so it does not let me to setOnClickListener

Comment: download the complete source from here https://github.com/ItsRajesh4uguys/ListwithDifferentClick/

Comment: Thnx, I will try today later on, yours work perfect by in my case mydat.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(rContext, "image ", 1000).show();

                        Intent image= new Intent(rContext,ImageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(image);
                    }
                }); thrwos an error : at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)

Comment: Yes For text is working, but for ImageView not. I will send my BaseAdapter class later on, because now due to Forum i can not.

Answer (score 0):

It has two solutions:
1) Instead on writing onItemClickListener for list you can do findviewbyid the textview and imageview in your custom adapter in getview method and then set onclick listeners on both of them.

2) You can use getChildAt method.... and check which child is your imageview and which is your textview. This is a work around so not much guaranteed.

Comment: holder.imageMap.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)mContenxt);  holder.textView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)mContenxt); But how can I check which in Main Activity which activity should start

Comment: holder.imageMap.setonClickListener(new onClickListener(){  inside onclick method you can pass the intent you need to open. as Intent i =new Intent(getActivityContext,ImageActivity.class);    getActivityContext.startActivity(i);

Comment: it throws an Error, I am doing exactly the same.

Comment: at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)

Comment: Just clean the project and run if again the error comes then check which line causes the problem......

Answer (score -1):

In your `MyBaseAdapterItemActivity`, `setOnClickListener((OnCLickListener)mContext)` to the ImageVIew and TextView.

In your activity, extends `OnClickListener`.
write your `startActivity(Intent)` in the `OnClick(View v)` depending on `v.getId()`

Comment: I get the folowing error, it does not let me to implement. Sorry for this bad formatting, but I can not answer now due Answer hours, so i decidd to write a comment. Any idea
holder.imageMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent((OnClickListener)mContenxt, ActivityName.class ); // Error the Constructor Intent((onClickListernt)mContext,Class<ActivityName>not fouund>) is
        

        
        }// END BaseAdapter

Answer (score -1):

In list item xml, for  set android:onClick="onFirstLinkClick" and similarly for the image view also, 
and the use following method in your activity

```
public void onFirstLinkClick(View V) {
```

}

Comment: both image and text have something common. which means by clicking each of them should carry some identifiers.